# Corners in straight parts of image with cv.goodFeaturesToTrack in Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, corner-detection

I'm trying to find the corners of a binary image in Python using cv.goodFeaturesToTrack. Here is a sample result: [image]

As is visible, there are many corners on seemingly straight parts of the image. How can I make the CV goodFeaturesToTrack algorithm look with a larger scope past the small deformities in straight lines and more towards the larger deformities that represent actual corners?

Here is the exact function I am calling:

```
corners = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(temp, 15, 0.1, 10)
```

Reducing the maximum number of corners doesn't help either since actual corners start to disappear before "corners" in straight parts of the image.

Comment: Can you provide original image? And how many is your desired numbers of corner, 5?

Comment: Corner detectors, such as Harris and Shi-Tomasi works best on right angle corners align with x-y axes. You are seeing corners from the rough edges of your feature at small scale, because your block size argument is likely too small (default=3). See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga1d6bb77486c8f92d79c8793ad995d541. Try increasing it and see if that helps. But your main corner at the bottom of your image is likely hard to detect, because it is an obtuse angle (not very sharp) and not aligned along the x-y axes.